# AS3 parameter coercion

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a simple question,in the below example when i created a new TransitionManager and pass `this` as a parameter a error occured that says Implicit coercion `this` is type Class.Why i have to typecast the Object in order to work,i thought object becomes a MovieClip after it extends it.

```
package {

 import fl.transitions.*;
 import fl.transitions.easing.*;
 import flash.display.MovieClip;
 import flash.events.MouseEvent;

 public class Border extends MovieClip
 {   
   var trManager:TransitionManager = new TransitionManager( MovieClip(this) ); //<--

   public function Border( ) {
   }   

   public function doRotate ( ev : MouseEvent)
   {
      trManager.startTransition({type:Rotate, direction:Transition.OUT, duration:3, easing:Strong.easeInOut, ccw:false, degrees:90});
   }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you stumbled across a strange oddity in the Flex compiler.

For a while, it seemed like the `this` referred to the static class type, but I was wrong, it seems to be just a bug in the compiler, misinterpreting the type of `this` at compile time.

I wouldn't recommend using this approach though, as the members will be initialized before the constructor is called. Have a look at this example:

```
package  
{
    public class Foo
    {
        private var bar1:Bar = new Bar("at bar1", Foo(this));

        public function Foo()
        {
            var bar2:Bar = new Bar("in constructor", this);
        }

        private var bar3:Bar = new Bar("at bar3", Foo(this));
    }
}

class Bar {

    public function Bar(scope: String, x:*):void {
        trace(scope, x is Foo);
    }

}
```

and the obvious answer is:

```
at bar1 true
at bar3 true
in constructor true
```

If the constructor was actually suppose to do some real initializations, you would actually use it uninitialized.

In conclusion, keep it simple, move the field initialization in constructor, that's what they are for anyway.

```
var trManager:TransitionManager;

public function Border( ) {
    trManager = new TransitionManager(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very constructive although i was a little bit confused with the line `you would actually use it uninitialized`.If it makes any difference i use Flash.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't express myself clearly. Not a big issue, just something to look out for.. 


If you check the output of my example, you will notice that the constructor body is executed last. Imagine you have a constructor that has a few parameters which will set to some members of the class. Those parameters are not going to be set yet if you use `this` to initialise other members like above.

Comment: Ok i understand what you are saying.I have a question,how can you pass a parameter into `Foo(this)` since the constructor is not set to accept parameters?

Comment: `Foo(this)` is just a cast. You could just as easily write it as `this as Foo`. Where do you want to pass a parameter to?

Comment: Sorry you are write is a typecast,i saw it in your example and i confused i thought you created a instance of `Foo` and pass `this` as a parameter.Thanks mate you honestly helped me.

Comment: Glad to be of service, but I'm still intrigued why the compiler treats `this` as a Class. :)